# How to convert JqueryMobile website to ipad, tab website

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have created a website using jquerymobile for smartPhones like iphone, android etc. Now i want to convert this website to ipad, tab website. How can i convert it? I am not sure is this jquerymobile working for both smartPhones and ipad???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, jQuery Mobile works on all mobile devices, you do not need to make changes. You can, however, make an optimized version for tablets.